# Need an advice about JDBC encrypted embedded database

Tags: database, encryption, jdbc, h2

I create a JavaFX desktop application and need to store data in encrypted storage.
At first I wanted to store the encrypted raw data in tables as it's done on server, but with this approach I loose an ability to search it and if I want so - I need to keep everything decrypted in memory, every time.
So, I found that H2 database supports encryption, but It supports only AES-128, and I've not found anything about AES-256 which I use now. 
Moreover, I've not found any discussion on the internet about it or plans to implements, or requests of this functionality.
So, why there is not information about it, Is it really that nobody needs it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is an option for you to use the very popular SQLite database instead. The SQLite Encryption Extension supports AES-256. See: https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/readme.wiki

Edit:
This is the version of SQLite with built-in encryption support: https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt

Comment: I saw this option, but there are lots of crunches, it's written in C and I need to compile something to make it use the encryption and so on, looks weird.

Comment: No, you can just use it out of the box via a Maven dependency. See: https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt

Comment: I also found that Derby Database perfectly fits my needs, the only flaw is that it doesn't support "GCM"

Comment: As I see sqlite-jdbc-crypt also doesn't support "GCM", only "CBC" which is vulnerable to oracle padding attacks